# URL rewrite rules not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

current URL

```
http://mywebsite.com/explore.php?location=india&search_query=about&filter[]=v
```

Desired URL

```
http://mywebsite.com/explore/india/about/v
```

Rules used:

```
RewriteRule ^explore/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /explore.php?location=$1&search_query=$2&filter[]=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify that your words can be more than one character. I think you need something more like :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^explore/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /explore.php?location=$1&search_query=$2&filter[]=$3 [L]
```

With

```
http://mywebsite.com/explore/india/about/v
```

if you output `$_GET` in `explore.php`, you would get :

```
array(3) { 
    ["location"]=> string(5) "india" 
    ["search_query"]=> string(5) "about" 
    ["filter"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(6) "v" 
    } 
}
```

Your actual `RewriteRule` worked for something like :

```
http://mywebsite.com/explore/i/a/v
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is working when I enter desired URL in the address bar but the current URL is not being redirected to the desired URL.